Ensuring Secure User Authentication in Flutter with ADB2C and aad_b2c_webview
We seek advice on ensuring security while using aad_b2c_webview in our Flutter app to avoid "Bad Request" errors during ADB2C authentication.
We are using ADB2C for user authentication in our Flutter mobile app. During the login process, we utilize the Flutter package "AppAuth" to open the login screen (WebView). The custom policy-based login flow of AADB2C runs on this WebView. However, if the user temporarily switches the app to the background to check the two-factor authentication code sent via email and then returns to the app, a "Bad Request" error appears, and authentication fails.
This issue has been identified as a problem with using Chrome Custom Tabs. Switching to the official Flutter package 'aad_b2c_webview' resolves the issue. Nonetheless, using an embedded WebView for OAuth 2.0 / OpenID Connect login processes is generally discouraged.
The reasons include:

WebView allows the application to execute JavaScript, potentially compromising user credentials and cookies in a malicious app.
The URL can be hidden, preventing users from verifying they are accessing the correct address.
Sessions are separated from the system browser, meaning SSO does not work.

We already understand the recommended approach of initiating the login process using the system browser and returning to the app via URL schemes upon completion. However, since no other methods proved effective, using aad_b2c_webview was the only solution to resolve the "Bad Request" issue.
We seek advice on ensuring security while utilizing aad_b2c_webview.
Devices experiencing the issue:

OPPO A73 (Android 11): Frequent occurrence
OPPO Reno5A (Android 12): Rare occurrence
OPPO Reno3A (Android 11)
AQUOS sense4 lite SH-RM15 (Android 12)
arrows We F-51B (Android 12): 2 occurrences

Versions of Flutter and AppAuth package being used:

Flutter: 3.7.12
Dart: 2.19.6
AppAuth: 4.2.1


We were using flutter_appauth for authentication, but we have confirmed that using aad_b2c_webview avoids the "Bad Request" issue.

